# Is it possible to force Lync to save conversation history without delay?

Tags: lync, lync-2010

I am using Microsoft Lync 2010 version 4 running on Windows 7. It is hooked up to our exchange server, and it is set to "Save instant message conversations in my email Conversation History folder". This does work sometimes, but my problem is there is a big delay between having a conversation and saving one.

If I leave the window open for 5-10 minutes after my conversation is over it will display:

"This conversation is saved in the Conversations tab in Lync and in the Conversation History folder in Outlook."

And then I can go find it in Outlook, but more often I close the messenger window when the conversation is over and then it does not get saved.

Is there anyway to force Lync to save ALL conversations? It seems insane that they couldn't include a hook for when the window is closed.

Comment: @Dee2000 has the correct answer. Just press `CTRL-S` to save to "Conversation History".

Comment: I agree, @Dee2000's answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't configurable using a Lync client policy or a GPO or a reg hack from what I've seen.

To get around this problem, I personally use the Microsoft Lync 2010, [tabbed conversations app](http://lync.microsoft.com/Adoption-and-Training-Kit/tools-and-apps/Pages/Tabbed-Conversations.aspx).

That way I can just leave conversation windows open but in a manageable way.

Comment: Thank you, that does look like the best solution short of switching to a decent messenger app :)

Answer (score 23):

What I do is hit Ctrl-S to "save now" rather than wait till Lync decides it'll save.

I was hoping to find (here) a property in the registry or a .ini file where you can reduce the 5-10 minute delay down to something more useful. No luck so far though.

Comment: Outside of doing it automatically, I think this is the correct solution... hitting Ctrl+S makes it save and you get that "This conversation is saved..." message. So just hit that before closing.